# How can I use PHP values in .js Extension Files?

Tags: javascript, php

```
var Facilites = {
    "91": {
        "facilites": "Wifi:Fans:AC",
        "RoomcatgId": "91"
    },
    "95": {
        "RoomcatgId": "95",
        "facilites": "Air Cooler:Daily Newspaper:Wifi:Fans"
    }
}
```

In Above code I want to Add PHP Wordpress Code in facilities field, But How Can I put PHP Codes in .js Extension Files?

```
<?php
$facilities = get_field_object('facilities');
value = $facilities['value'];
echo "<span>";
    if( $value ):
        foreach( $value as $val ):
            $fac = implode( ":", $facilities['choices'][ $val ] );
                echo $fac;
        endforeach;
    endif;
echo "</span>"; 
?>
```

in the field facilities I want to add above PHP code like:

```
"91": { "facilities": "<?php #php code here ?>" }
```

Comment: Could you not just rename the `.js` file to something like `.js.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

The result depends on how your code/files work together but it is possible. You don't need to add PHP code to your .js file. That file can't process PHP code. Unless the javascript code is in the .php file as well.

Try this (I just copied your code, didn't check it):

```
<?php
$facilities = get_field_object('facilities');
value = $facilities['value'];
$myJSValues = "";
    if( $value ):
        foreach( $value as $val ):
            $fac = implode( ":", $facilities['choices'][ $val ] );
                $myJSValues .= $fac;
        endforeach;
    endif;
?>
<script>
var myValues = <?php echo $myJSValues; ?>
</script>
```

in your .js file use `myValues`